# how to have horizontal line

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

**This is my formula:**

```
StringVar ReplaceString;

ReplaceString :="<U>"+ Replace ({command.ExtraPersons}, ",", "<br>")+"</U>";
ReplaceString
```

**Output is:**

```
{command.ExtraPersons}
{command.ExtraPersons}
```

How to have this output?
**Expected output:**

```
{command.ExtraPersons}        __________________________
{command.ExtraPersons}        __________________________
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code does not compile. Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi DrKoch, i wanted to have horizontal line after {command.ExtraPersons}, my formula above only displays {command.Extraperson} no horizontal line after it. :(

Comment: horizontal line below the field or beside the field?

Comment: beside the field.. how?

Comment: you can just draw the line beside the field

Comment: Hi Siva, I want to add the line by a formula how?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the report document and click on Insert and select Line, then you can draw a line as you expected.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuPEG.png

Comment: The author was asking about a programmatic way to output a horizontal line and not how to select this option from UI.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on the report document and click on Insert and select Line, then you can draw a line as you expected.

Comment: It is not clear to what you are referring...an IDE?  Please give further information.

Comment: I'm referring crystal report document. that mean  example.rpt  file. When you open this example.rpt file, it will show you the document default section1 ,section2...section5.   On the document you can right click on any section and then click Insert > select Line to draw a line